# Why are browsers omitting the Referer header when requesting source maps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, source-maps

I tested it in Chrome and Firefox, both of them will not include the Referer header when requesting JavaScript source maps. What is the reason for that, is it by design? Couldn't find any documentation explaining this behavior.

Comment: What would be the reason for including it?

Comment: The "page" requesting the source map would likely be the embedded devtools extension anyway

Comment: Did not realize that, this is probably the correct answer.